# which soap Api is used to make reservation for multiple passenger in Sabre

Tags: xml, wsdl, sabre

I am using Sabre SOAP API, i get the response from Bargain Max Finder SOAP. 

Now i want to make reservation for the number of searched Passengers. which SOAP API is used to make reservation for multiple passenger in Sabre. 
Secondly is there any SOAP API to pass passenger information in request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of two APIs in order to book air itinerary and submit passenger information, to complete a PNR:

EnhancedAirBook:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking

PassengerDetails:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Passenger_Details